# How to find optimality conditions for a linear program with constraints $Ax \le b$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have a feasible point $\hat{x}$ for the problem
$$\min c^Tx \quad \text{subject to} \ Ax \le b$$
and I would like to determine if $\hat{x}$ is optimal.
The KKT conditions seem to provide no information. Indeed, the Lagrangian is
$$L(x, \lambda) = c^Tx - \lambda^T(b-Ax)$$
so the KKT conditions are: $x^*$ is optimal if there exists a $\lambda^*$ such that
\begin{align}
A^T\lambda^* &= c \\
\lambda^* &\ge 0.
\end{align}
Thus, given a $\hat x$, the KKT conditions do not help us classify it as optimal or suboptimal (unless of course the KKT conditions are infeasible, in which case there is no optimal solution).

Comment: Did you forget the other KKT condition: $\text{diag}\left(\lambda\right)\left(Ax-b\right)=0$?

Comment: The KKT conditions are equivalent to the dual, so unless there are simplifying characteristics (structure, dimensions, bounds, etc) they will not clarify.

Comment: Not that it matters, but the above should be $A^T \lambda +c =0, \lambda \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**KKT Conditions**

For an optimization problem: $\min f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$ subject to $g_{i}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\leq 0\phantom{x}\forall\phantom{x}i\in\{1,...,n\}$. The necessary condition for a local optima is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{0}&=
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\left[f(\mathbf{x})+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_{i}\cdot g_{i}(\mathbf{x})\right]
\\\\
0&\geq
g_{i}(\mathbf{x})\phantom{x}\forall\phantom{x}i\in\{1,...,n\}
\\\\
0&\leq \lambda_{i}\phantom{x}\forall\phantom{x}i\in\{1,...,n\}
\\\\
0&=
\lambda_{i}\cdot g_{i}(\mathbf{x})\phantom{x}\forall\phantom{x}i\in\{1,...,n\}
\end{aligned}
$$

The conditions are stationarity, primal feasibility, dual feasibility, and complementary slackness respectively. Together, they are conditions for a point to be a stationary point in the feasible region.

**KKT Conditions In Linear Programming**

In linear problems, the gradients are not functions of $\mathbf{x}$. Therefore, we don't need a test point to check the existence of optima. An optima exists in the feasible region if and only if the stationarity and dual feasibility conditions are met:

$$
\exists\lambda\geq \mathbf{0}:\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{\lambda}=\mathbf{c}
$$

After obtaining $\mathbf{\lambda}$, to check if a point $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ is an optima and is in the feasible region, use the remaining KKT conditions: primal feasibility and complementary slackness:

$$
\mathbf{A}\hat{\mathbf{x}} \leq \mathbf{b}
\phantom{x}
\text{and}
\phantom{x}
\text{diag}(\mathbf{\lambda})\left(\mathbf{A}\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\mathbf{b}\right)=\mathbf{0}
$$

**TLDR**

You have only used two out of four KKT conditions. Those two conditions are for proving that an optima exists in the feasible region.